# Interfacing static and non static methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, interface, static, dependency-injection

Ok so my problem is trying to interface static and non-static methods, an example of both.

Regards.

Examples:

Codeigniter AR(non-static) and

php-activeRecord(static)

### Interface

```
interface userRepoInterface
{

    public  function get($id=null); //should be static or non-static

}
```

### Php-ActiveRecord

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model implements userRepoInterface
{

    public static function get ( $id = null )
    {
        try
        {
            if(is_null($id)){
                $user = self::all();
            }
            elseif(is_int($id)){
                $user = self::find($id);
            }

        }catch(ActiveRecord\RecordNotFound $e)
        {
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return ($user) ?:$user;
    }
}
```

### Codeigniter AR

```
class CIUser extends CI_Model implements userRepoInterface
{

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct () ;
    }

    public function get ( $id = null )
    {
        if ( is_null ( $id ) ) {
             $user = $this->db->get('users');
        }
        elseif ( is_int($id) ) {
            $user = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id'=> $id));
        }

        return ($user->num_rows() > 0) ? $user->result() : false;
    }

}
```

-

### TestCase Library(Authenticate)

```
class Authenticate
{

    protected $userRepository;


    public function __construct (  userRepoInterface $userRepository )
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        print'<pre>';
        print_r($this->userRepository->get());
    }

    public function __get ( $name )
    {
        $instance =&get_instance();
        return $instance->$name;
    }
}
```

-

### TestCase Controller

```
public function index ()
    {

        $model1 = new \User; //this is static
        $model2 = $this->load->model('CIUser'); //this is non-static

        $this->load->library('Authenticate', $model1);

    }
```

Comment: I don't think that mixing static and non-static usage for method is a good idea.

Comment: mixing ? Im just trying to decouple my Authenticate library.

Comment: They both use the same interface so it interface states that method is static or not, all implementers must follow it.

Comment: This is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable solution I see in this case is making it static in interface and something like this in classes where instance is to be used:

```
public static function get ( $id = null )
{
    $instance = new static;

    if ( is_null ( $id ) ) {
         $user = $instance->db->get('users');
    }
    elseif ( is_int($id) ) {
        $user = $instance->db->get_where('users', array('id'=> $id));
    }

    return ($user->num_rows() > 0) ? $user->result() : false;
}
```